# How to show coordinate on a GeoExplorer map by moving the mouse?

Tags: boundless-suite, openlayers-2, geoexplorer

I am new in developing a GIS web page. I am using OpenGeo suite 4.6 at my work and I want to show the coordinate on the GeoExplorer map. I know that OpenLayers use a code for showing the coordinate of the map (`new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition()`), but I don't know where and how I should add this code?

Comment: Can you please be more specific what did you change and in which file apart from adding the code in the composer.html ? I've added the code to the composer.html but it's not enough to show the coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to show coordinates in geo-explorer within opengeosuite:

1. open the composer.html in the template folder
2. at the end of the code  add the following code:
   app.mapPanel.map.addControl(
      new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition( { prefix: ' Lon ', separator: ' , Lat ',
       numDigits: 2,
       displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")})
        );
   Since the default style in set to show the coordinates at the bottom left , change the openlayer style (style.css) to make changes to the display.