# Coordinate system disappears when I use publish map and iframe tag in GeoExplorer?

Tags: coordinate-system, boundless-suite, geoexplorer

I managed to add xy coordinate in GeoExplorer, I use OpenGeo suite to use GeoExplorer. I added the OpenLayers mouse position code to the composer in order to show the coordinates. Please consider my previous question and answer:

[how to show coordinate on a geoexplorer map by moving the mouse?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/151783/how-to-show-coordinate-on-a-geoexplorer-map-by-moving-the-mouse)

The problem is, when I publish my map and use iframe tag the coordinate system will disappear. I even changed the "viewer" to "composer" in iframe tag, but still no result.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add your new tool to the viewerTools array as well, did you do this?

https://github.com/boundlessgeo/suite/blob/master/geoexplorer/app/static/script/app/GeoExplorer.js#L125

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Since I am new in using geoexplorer I am not very familiar with the code. I didnt add a new tool to the viewerTools array. I didnt find config.viewerTools = ({ //etc}) in GeoExplorer.js, however, the code exists in GeoExplorer-debug.js. when I add the whole code you mentioned in your comment to GeoExplorer.js the geoexplorer stops working.  Would you please give me some more hints how should I add a new tool to GeoExplorer.js?